# CRM 2013 Views - Add Find Columns option is missing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to add a custom field to be able to search on when clicking search in the lookup. I have added the custom column (Social Security Number) to Lookup view, Client Search view and Quick Find view but still no results are displayed when searching on the social security number.

In this article is said to "Add Find Columns":
www.microsoft.com/.../edit-the-quick-find-view.aspx

I don't see "Add Find Columns" when I edit my views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a find column in CRM 2013 you need to open the Quick Find view related to the entity,  inside you will find the option `Add find Columns` on the right menu.

[image]